# Yajra/Jquery datatable how to exclude records based on condition

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

How can I exclude data based on my condition on the addColumn function?

What I tried is this but it will include records that are > 0

```
    ->addColumn('total', function ($row) {
        $arr = array(abs($row->fba_fee_count),abs($row->referral_fee_count));
        if($arr > 0) {
            return array_sum($arr);
        }
```

On the frontend side, I also tried

```
    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        if ( data.total === 0 ) {
            $(row).hide();
        }
    },
```

Now it hides the data but the pagination is showing for all the data. As you can see in the image below. I got 3 records but the pagination is for all the records.

[image]

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: us this ```if(sizeof($arr) > 0)```

Comment: can you show controller method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better you can restrict in query if sum of total is greater than zero .

```
$result= ModelName::havingRaw('(referral_fee_count+fba_fee_count)>0')->get();
```

or

```
$result=ModelName::having(DB::raw('referral_fee_count+fba_fee_count'),'>',0)->get();
```

Also for yajra datatable no need to use `get()` .

Comment: Thanks for this one. I already solved it and this really helps.